# ios Is it possible to send facebook messages to facebook friends?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an iOS app that needs to send messages to friends, in behalf of the logged in user.

Lets say user A has logged in into my app.

I have a list of all his friends, from which he can select some. Is it possible to send a private message to the selected friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the answer to your question is no.

It's not possible via the graph api to send messages. This was removed some time ago due to potential abuse.

They do have though the XMPP/Jabber interface which does however have limitations that a message would not have.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/