# How to send personal message to my Facebook friends in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I want to send personal message to my facebook friends using facebook ios framework.

So, Kindly confirm whether that is possible or not using facebook sdk/framework in iOS.

Comment: i have same problem i went send message with api facebook

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864787/ios-is-it-possible-to-send-facebook-messages-to-facebook-friends)